# TLS Session Resumption via Pre-Shared Key (PSK) in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.3, tls-psk

Currently the [TLS Session Resumption documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_session_resumption) for Node.js only covers two methods (Session IDs and Session Tickets) both of which are obsoleted in the TLS 1.3 spec. In practice I've found that Filezilla is not utilizing either of these methods over TLS 1.3 when the server is configured to handle them.

That was confirmed to me by a Filezilla team member, they only utilize the Pre-Shared Key method as specified in TLS 1.3.

Which brought me to the [PSK docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_pre_shared_keys), which are sadly even more sparse and dated than the session resumption docs. They don't even cover exchanging a PSK during the handshake and instead focus on out of band PSK. I've been digging through the Node source but am not finding anything very helpful since most of this stuff is in the deps -> OpenSSL and my skills at deciphering C are not great.

It is quite possible that my question is not suitable for this medium, if so I understand if it is closed. That said, my question is simply: Can PSK based session resumption be achieved in Node.js at all at this point and if so, what would that flow look like?